# Change the size of subplots for polar projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I am plotting a 3x3 grid of polar projections (that look a bit like radar plots).

e.g. exactly as in this example:
https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html

I am managing to plot the data as intended, but would now like to scale each polar projection by a variable, so that some of the circle are bigger than others, as in the figure below.
[image: scale either by width/height or area]

What are the commands I need to apply to the axis as I cycle through subplots?

I have tried turning on/off autoscale. 
It is possible that gridspec.Gridspec() might work, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution, although it might well be.
Thanks

Comment: This will be easier if you post a minimal, complete working example, but since you are using a polar projection, it might be sufficient to scale the radius with this individual variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question.

You can also use directly `fig.add_axes()` to have a continuous space in which you place your plots:

```
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2], polar=True) # Left, Bottom, Width, Height
ax2 = f.add_axes([0.30, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6], polar=True)
r = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax2.plot(theta, r)
```

[image: polar plot with different size]

---

Less good version

You can try to set different Axes size when you create them:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r

ax = plt.subplot2grid((2,3), (0,0), polar=True)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,3), (0,1), rowspan=2, colspan=2, polar=True)
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax2.plot(theta, r)
```

[image: polar plot with different size]

You can have a bigger grid than 2x3 and have more granularity on the size of the plot.

(Don't mind the different graphic styles)

HTH

Comment: thanks - I hadn't thought about using a bigger grid than 2x3. That may work in some cases. I am currently having mixed results using `gridspec(..., widthratios=[], heightratios=[])`

Comment: Thanks - second option appears to be the best solution!

Comment: Yes, I think so too. Accept the answer to let people know it solves your problem. (if it solved your problem!)

Comment: Alas - I realise that gridspec is not a good solution as the ratios refer to the rows/ columns, not individual subplots.